# Sufficient conditions for applying Taylor theorem

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

Consider a real-valued function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Is assuming $f(.)$ twice differentiable at $a \in \mathbb{R}$ enough to apply the Taylor Theorem stating
$$
f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{1}{2}f''(a)(x-a^2)+o(|x-a|) \text{   as $x\rightarrow a$}
$$

I'm asking this because in some notes I have found these alternative set of sufficient conditions:

"*$f(.)$ twice continuously differentiable in a neighbourhood of $a \in \mathbb{R}$*"

[I know that having $f(.)$ twice differentiable at $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is not enough in order to give a closed form to $o(|x-a|)$].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twice differentiable at $a$ is sufficient. Have a look at [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem).

By the way you even have $$
f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{1}{2}f''(a)(x-a^2)+o(|x-a|^2)$$ with the square in the $o$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is enough. Consider the function
$$g(x) = f(x) - f(a) - f'(a)(x-a) - \frac12 f''(a)(x-a)^2.$$
It is clear that $g$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of $a$ with
$$g'(x) = f'(x) - f'(a) - f''(a) (x-a).$$
Since $f$ is twice differentiable in $a$, we have
$$g'(x) = f'(x) - f'(a) - f''(a) (x-a) = o(|x-a|).$$
Finally, we apply the mean value theorem to $g$ in order to achieve
$$f(x) - f(a) - f'(a)(x-a) - \frac12 f''(a)(x-a)^2 = g(x) - g(a) = g'(\xi) \, (x-a)$$
for some $\xi \in (0,a)$.
Putting things together, we have
$$f(x) - f(a) - f'(a)(x-a) - \frac12 f''(a)(x-a)^2 = o(|x-a|^2).$$